# Jenkins Android Library - Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, jenkins

I'm brand new to Jenkins and I'm trying to compile an Android Library that is a Maven project. However, I keep getting an Unsupported major.minor version 51.0. I have read a few answers that say that changed the JRE will fix this, but we are developing in an Eclipse environment, and changing the compiler in Eclipse does not change it in Jenkins.

Any help on how to solve this in Jenkins will be much appreciated.

The error:

```
java.io.IOException: Remote call on Channel to Maven [java, -cp, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-agent-1.5.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/apache-maven-3.0.5/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/apache-maven-3.0.5/conf/logging, jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main, /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/apache-maven-3.0.5, /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.48.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar, 41982] failed  



Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/eventspy/EventSpy : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue while switching from java 7 to 8, this is what we did:

1) Access Jenkins home(from browser) ip:port#
2) Click on "Manage Jenkins"
3) Click on "Configure system"
4) Under the JDK section, install the correct version (version that the code is compiled, in your case, same version as Eclipse). And set it to default.

gl!

Comment: Oh thank you very much! However it looks like we already have JDK 7 and I believe the major.minor 51.0 is JDK7. I will mess around with this setting though

Comment: You are right. 51.0 would generally mean that code was compiled in JDK7 but tried to run in JDK6. Try to see what your system default (Jenkins machine) JDK is. If the version is 1.6, making 1.7 default might just do it.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much!